# Pre defined voice software for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: audacity

I make videos or at times translate videos to local languages. Currently, I record using Audacity and simply export as mp3. It is a bit difficult to make my voice sound better in Audacity. Is there any software which can give a predefined male voice (or female) which is of professional sound quality. I translate these videos for free of cost to help local users understand about computers and gadgets. It will be nice if you can give a helping hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text2wave`  that comes with `festival` for the purpose.

To install `festival`, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install festival
```

Now open a terminal and type,

```
text2wave -o ./filename.wav ./filename.txt
```

Where `./filename.wav` is the file where converted audio will be saved and `./filename.txt` is the file from which text is taken.You can also use pdfs.

You can also pipe the output of some command to `text2wave`. For example

```
echo "This is some text"|text2wave -o ./filename.wav
```

The output may not be as good as you expect, so to increase the quality of voices, follow this [tutorial on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751169).

> **NOTE:** There is an simple yet excellent tool called `spd-say` preinstalled in Ubuntu. The problem is that it only outputs to audio device and not a file.

Comment: I am afraid text to speech won't work for me as I make some in regional languages as well. Also, I deal with tech terms like Android, Gwibber etc, so text to speech may make it worse. I have WINE, will I be able to use one of the pre defined voice software on Ubuntu. Any good free ones you can suggest ? I just need one simple and decent output. Thanks by the way.